# Raspberry Pi rc.local does not execute

Tags: python, linux, startup

I am trying to execute a python temperature monitoring script on my Raspberry Pi at startup, using the rc.local file, but I have not been able to get it to work after a number of attempts. Currently my rc.local looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

# start the temperature monitoring program
python /home/pi/TemperatureMonitoring/TempMonitor.py >> /var/log/rc.local.log 2>&1 &

exit 0
```

As you can see I have set it to log the python outputs into a file, however the file does not get created at all during startup.

Checking the status of the rc local service I get this output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status rc-local.service
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; static)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
           └─ttyoutput.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-03-27 12:03:53 CEST; 44s ago
  Process: 565 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Warning: Unit file changed on disk, 'systemctl daemon-reload' recommended.
```

I have set the rc.local file to be executable, and the permissions look ok:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /etc/rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 549 Mar 27 12:03 /etc/rc.local
```

Also when I try running rc.local as root from the terminal it executes properly and the log file gets created (even though it's empty when opened):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sh /etc/rc.local
/etc/rc.local: 1: /etc/rc.local: #!/bin/sh: not found
My IP address is 192.168.5.36 
/etc/rc.local: 21: /etc/rc.local: cannot create /var/log/rc.local.log: Permission denied

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo /etc/rc.local
/etc/rc.local: 1: /etc/rc.local: #!/bin/sh: not found
My IP address is 192.168.5.36
```

Also, here is this output (I have seen this command suggested when researching the issue, I'm not sure what it does though):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start
[....] Starting rc.local (via systemctl): rc.local.serviceWarning: Unit file of rc.local.service changed on disk, 'systemctl daemon-reload' recommended.
Job for rc-local.service failed. See 'systemctl status rc-local.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
 failed!
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

This is the part in the boot sequence from the syslog file where the rc.local seems to fail:

```
Mar 27 13:48:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Mar 27 13:48:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Network is Online.
Mar 27 13:48:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
Mar 27 13:48:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start NTP daemon...
Mar 27 13:48:54 raspberrypi systemd[568]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/rc.local: Exec format error
Mar 27 13:48:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Mar 27 13:48:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: rc-local.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Mar 27 13:48:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
Mar 27 13:48:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit rc-local.service entered failed state.
```

Comment: #!/bin/sh in /etc/rc.local change to #!/bin/bash

Comment: Nothing changes unfortunately (the same 203 status code, etc).

Comment: could you post rc.local

Comment: Seems like it's too long to paste here, but the only things I have changed compared to the one I pasted in the original post are the #!bin/bash as you suggested, and I have changed the name of the python script (I have created a very simple test script to make sure that isn't the cause of the issue).